# How to test spring controller handler response

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, junit

I have spring controller handler. I have to test that handle by using Junit test case. I am new to Juint so not able to test Junit. I want to run this in eclipse.

spring handler:

```
@Controller  
@RequestMapping("/core")  
public class HelloController  {  
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getEntityType", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
     public ResponseEntity<List<MyEnum >> getEntityType(HttpServletRequest  
 request, HttpServletResponse response) {     
  return new ResponseEntity<List<MyEnum >>(Arrays.asList(MyEnum.values()), HttpStatus.OK);    
        }
```

Enum Class:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    FIRST, SECOND, THIRD;
}
```

TestCase:

```
@Test
public void testToFindEnumTypes() throws Exception {
    MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest("GET", "core/getEntityType");
    MockHttpServletResponse response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
    hello.Controller.getEntityType(request, response);
    Assert.assertNotNull(getResponseJSON(response));
}
```

Please tell me how to Run Junit Test case for that handler. I am new to Junit testing.

Comment: You'll need to provide some more detail.  Where do you want to run this from?  An IDE?  A Maven build?  Are you getting specific errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Eclipse, there should be a green run button that allows you to run JUnit tests.

Eclipse Help has this really good article explaining how to:
https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsptopic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-junit.htm

Also, if running outside your Eclipse, and doing it in a maven build, you need to add junit dependency to your maven pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>junit</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
     <version>4.12</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then run maven test command as follows:

```
mvn clean test
```

---

Also, there a few syntax errors in your posted code. It should be like something like this:

```
public class HelloControllerTest {

private HelloController helloController = new HelloController();

@Test
public void testToFindEnumTypes() throws Exception {
    // setup
    MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest("GET", "core/getEntityType");
    MockHttpServletResponse response = new MockHttpServletResponse();

    // execution
    ResponseEntity actualResponse = helloController.getEntityType(request, response);

    // verify
    assertNotNull(actualResponse);
    assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, actualResponse.getStatusCode());

    List<MyEnum> myEnumList = (List<MyEnum>) actualResponse.getBody();
    assertTrue(myEnumList.contains(MyEnum.FIRST));
    assertTrue(myEnumList.contains(MyEnum.SECOND));
    assertTrue(myEnumList.contains(MyEnum.THIRD));

}
```

Ideally, you should also verify correctly all the return values like i done in the example above.

Comment: thank you so much for your help i really appreciate it